# Unable to add frameworks in Xcode project

Tags: xcode, macos

[image]Steps folloed are

1)In the project editor, select the target to which you want to add a library or framework.

2)Click Build Phases at the top of the project editor.

3)Open the Link Binary With Libraries section.

4)Click the Add button (+) to add a library or framework.

5)And then selected a framework of my requirement. Nothing is getting added nor i am seeing any error msg. Please find below attached

I clicked Cancel and Ok in two different times, but files didnot got added. I didnot created any repository, i just downloaded some existing project from internet and trying to add frameworks to it. What should i give username and password.

[image]

Comment: Can you share whole image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By removing source control, i am able to add frame works to the project.

I removed source control by following steps
In Xcode, choose Xcode-> Preferences, and select Source Control and uncheck Enable Source Control option[image]